# incorrect outerHeight before refresh and on resize

Tags: jquery, dynamic, scroll, width, outerheight

[edited following your comments]

I'm seeking to dynamically assign a margin-top to a div (.main) which is below a fixed div (header) which dimensions varies depending on scroll positioning. This margin-top should be equal to the heigth of (header) when in its upper position (.smart).

The following code is working almost without a hitch:

```
   //first function to check the width of the page and assign a margin-top equal to           
   //header.outerHeight in its default position

    function checkWidth(){
    var winInnW = window.innerWidth;
    var $headerHeight;

if(winInnW<=640){
       $('header').addClass('smart');
       var $headerHeight = $('header.smart').outerHeight(true);
        $('.main').css({'marginTop': $headerHeight});
    }
    else
    {
        $('header').removeClass('smart');

    }

if((winInnW>640) && (winInnW<1280)){
       $('header').addClass('medium');
       var $headerHeight = $('header.medium').outerHeight(true);
        $('.main').css({'marginTop': $headerHeight});
    }
    else
    {
        $('header').removeClass('medium');

    }

if(winInnW>=1280){
       $('header').addClass('large');
       var $headerHeight = $('header.large').outerHeight(true);
        $('.main').css({'marginTop': $headerHeight});
    }
    else
    {
        $('header').removeClass('large');
    }}

checkWidth();
$(window).on('resize load', checkWidth);


// second function that checks the scroll hiatus and applies styles accordingly called 
//on scroll movement only
function checkScroll(){
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 10;
    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test){
        $('header').addClass('lower');
    }

    else{
        $('header').removeClass('lower')
    }}

$(window).on('scroll', checkScroll);
```

Problems here:

- on first opening the page on certain small windows it still takes a refresh for the margin to adjust (closing and subsequent reopenings of the page in the same resolution seems to works fine though)
- resizing to smaller window sizes on the fly, the margin fails to adjust and takes a refresh

Any pointers as to what i'm doing wrong?

Appreciated!

Comment: if you want to include margins: `$('#header').outerHeight(true); `

Comment: One question at a time, please. Simplify and separate.

Comment: does the header include images? if so you may want to set the margin on window.load

Comment: @isherwood sorry, edited and simplified as hinted

Comment: @A.Wolff looks like the .outerHeight(true) did not help :-(

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue? A simplified jsFiddle of course ;)

Comment: @Pete no image in the header, but its sizes depends on the window's width and varies with scroll position (2 sizes) would window.load solve this?

Comment: @Guillaume window.load will wait for all async elements to be loaded as images. That's way will give accurate size for all elements. But not sure you need it in your case, hard to figure out what you are looking for here

Comment: @A.Wolff here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tylomig/uP3T7/9/

Comment: This is exactly what i am trying to achieve, it works on the fiddle where the margin seems to be dynamically assigned! How come it doesn't work on my page? Could it be that the .upper_smart class is assigned by a function and not hardcoded in the html?

Comment: It could be because wrong or none DOCTYPE is set on your page. Any online link where we can see your issue in action?

Comment: @A.Wolff Progress! What happens is that i've got an earlier scroll function running that checks the scroll position and assigns a height to the header depending on the value returned. Now, i want to calculate my margin-top on the default (no scroll) settings but it still has to be evaluated by this scroll function! I checked and i'm getting the correct value when i embed outerHeight in this scroll function. This is some progress. Not sorted yet since i want to align my content BEFORE the scroll, but at least i know where to look for. Will try reworking the structure! Thanks for your help!